# Copy List of manually installed software from one server to another with same version

Tags: apt, server, software-installation, dpkg

I have 2 servers, let's say **Server1** and **Server2**

***Server1*** is configured long ago by some person which has multiple packages and our application has so many dependencies on those packages. So I want to maintain same set of Packages in new server ***i.e., Server2*** to run our application smoothly.

I used below command to list all the packages from ***Server1***

```
 dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list
```

Which gives all the Package List Like

```
accountsservice                                 install
acpid                                           install
adduser                                         install
amd64-microcode                                 install
...
...
```

I make a copy of the above package list in ***Server2*** and tried to install those Packages using a command

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list
```

but it says like

```
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 2: acpid
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 4: amd64-microcode
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 12: apt-transport-https
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 14: apt-xapian-index
...
...
```

Is there any other way to maintain same set of packages in both server?

Both are Same OS with different versions (server1 : Ubuntu 14.04 and server2: Ubuntu 20.04) and I want only user installed packages

**Update:**

```
apt list --installed
```

Above Command displays like

```
accountsservice/trusty-updates,now 0.6.35-0ubuntu7.3 amd64 [installed]
acpid/trusty,now 1:2.0.21-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
adduser/trusty,now 3.113+nmu3ubuntu3 all [installed]
amd64-microcode/trusty-updates,now 3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.14.04.2+really20130710.1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
apache2/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.22 amd64 [installed]
...
```

It displays package with version, Is it possible that I can save the result of this output and run in ***server2*** so that I can have same  Package with same version.

Comment: Your method likely won't work: Ubuntu 14.04 (note the correct name, get into that habit) is simply too different from Ubuntu 20.04 (again, note the correct name). Too many packages have changed over six years.

Comment: I don't want to install inbuilt Packages, I want a list only the one which are installed by user.

Answer (score 3):

A dpkg list is all apps, but only different ones will be installed. Often best to edit out old kernels.

From old install

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/my-packages
```

From new install:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
#IF you get this error:
dpkg: warning: package not in database
sudo apt-get install dselect
sudo dselect 
   -> Update
   -> Install
```

A tabular list of all manually installed packages can be obtained using aptitude which you probably have to install:

```
aptitude search '~i!~M'
```

Top level applications:

```
aptitude --disable-columns -F 'no_dependents %p' search '~i!~M!~R(~i)'
```

But you then may need to add the install to every line.

[How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Also how to list applications you installed.

[How to list all installed packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Comment: Yeah, Now I Got a list of manually installed packages using `aptitude search '~i!~M'
> packages`. So now how to use this list in server2. Again can I use `dselect`

Comment: Have not used aptitude, but I think it is just the list of apps. To use deselect it expects two columns, one name of app and second install. A dpkg export may include uninstall as a second column entry which means it was uninstalled & would not be reinstalled. Links show set  command to add install to each line using sed.

Answer (score 3):

Were it my system, here's how I would do it:

Packages installed by the user is tracked by apt-marking (see `man apt-mark`.)

However, there's a small problem: The Ubuntu installer apt-marks *everything* on a stock install of Ubuntu as manually-installed. It's a safety measure so folks don't erroneously uninstall their desktop.

So it's (sort of) simple subtraction: The list of all manual packages minus the list of stock install packages.

1. Get the list of packages on your 14.04 system that are apt-marked "manual".

   ```
   apt-mark showmanual > server1
   ```
2. Spin up a VM with a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install, and do the same thing.

   ```
   apt-mark showmanual > fresh
   ```
3. Diff the two files.

   ```
   diff --suppress-common-lines fresh server1
   ```
4. Go through the resulting short list, line by line. You must weed out kernel packages, investigate packages that have been dropped or renamed or otherwise changed, add packages that are no longer part of a stock install, etc. There is no easy or automated way to do it.